# create tasks in Airflow by looping over a list and pass arguments

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

edit: 
**This will work, I defined ex_func_airflow(var_1 = i) which was causing the issue**

I would like to create tasks in airflow by looping on a list.

```
tabs = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in tabs:
    task = PythonOperator(
    task_id = name,
    provide_context=False,
    op_args  = [i],
    python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
    dag=dag)
    task_0 >> task >> task_1
```

When this is run in airflow the argument that is passed is always the last element in that list.

So i'm essentially running:

```
ex_func_airflow(6)
```

five times instead of running

```
ex_func_airflow(1)
ex_func_airflow(2)
ex_func_airflow(3)
```

..etc.

How would can I pass the correct arguments for each task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following codes work for me.

```
def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    print("hello")


def ex_func_airflow(i):
    print(i)


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="loop_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2018, 12, 31),
)

task_0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_0',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag)

task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag)

tabs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in tabs:
    task_id = f'task_tab_{i}'
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        provide_context=False,
        op_args=[i],
        python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
        dag=dag)
    task_0 >> task >> task_1
```

Comment: Just found my bug, I defined the function like this..


def ex_func_airflow(var_1 = i):